# Making an AlertDialog wait for user input?

Tags: java, android

I'm having a hard time making the program respond properly because of the async AlertDialog. I want to make the program to do something AFTER user has closed the window regardless of pressing positive/negative button. Any ideas how to make the program wait? Any suggestions appreciated.

Here's the custom `AlertDialog` Class.

```
private DialogListener listener;

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialogfragment, null);
        final EditText numProd = view.findViewById(R.id.prodInput);
        final EditText discount = view.findViewById(R.id.popust);
        builder.setView(view)
                .setTitle("Input")
                .setNegativeButton("Back", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                        listener.getInput(1, 0.0);
                    }
                })
                .setPositiveButton("Confirm", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                        int prodnumber = 1;
                        if (!numProd.getText().toString().equals("") && !(Integer.parseInt(numProd.getText().toString()) < 0)) {
                            prodnumber = Integer.parseInt(numProd.getText().toString());
                        }
                        double discNum = 0.0;
                        if (!discount.getText().toString().equals("") && !(Double.parseDouble(discount.getText().toString()) < 0) && !(Double.parseDouble(discount.getText().toString()) > 100)) {
                            discNum = Double.parseDouble(discount.getText().toString());
                            discNum = discNum / 100;
                        } else if (!discount.getText().toString().equals("") && !(Double.parseDouble(discount.getText().toString()) < 0) && !(Double.parseDouble(discount.getText().toString()) > 1)) {
                            discNum = Double.parseDouble(discount.getText().toString());
                        }
                        listener.getInput(prodnumber, discNum);
                        dialogInterface.dismiss();
                    }
                });
        return builder.create();
    }
```

The second class, where I want the program to do some stuff for me:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case RC_BARCODE_CAPTURE:
                if (resultCode == CommonStatusCodes.SUCCESS) {
                    if (data != null) {
                        final Barcode barcode = data.getParcelableExtra(BarcodeCaptureActivity.BarcodeObject);
                        final String barcodeValue = barcode.displayValue;
                                  if (barcodes.contains(barcodeValue)) {
                            productNum = 1;
                            updateItem(barcodeValue);
                        } else {
                            inputDialog numInput = new inputDialog();
        numInput.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "NumberInput");
                            addProduct(barcodeValue);
                        }
                        adapter.notifyItemChanged(barcodes.indexOf(barcodeValue));
                    }
                } else {
                    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
                }
//implementing the interface in this class
     @Override
        public void getInput(int number, double discNum) {
            productNum = number;
            if (discNum != 0.0) {
                discount = discNum;
            }
        }
```

I know this is probably an amateur implementation but I'm trying.

Comment: "Any ideas how to make the program wait?" -- sorry, but that is not how Android app development works.

Comment: @CommonsWare And why is that?

Comment: @Kröw: Android uses a purely event-driven UI model. There are no blocking UI calls.

Comment: @CommonsWare yeah I know it can't be halted, but I want the rest of the program wait for the dialog to close/dismiss.

Comment: Again, that's now how Android UIs are constructed. As AGDownie notes, you can register callbacks to find out about events related to the dialog. There, you can take appropriate steps to continue doing whatever the user is requesting.

Answer (score 1):

You can't wait for the dialog to be dismissed, but you can perform an action when it is closed by whatever button (including the back key since your dialog appears to be cancellable).

Simply add a DialogInterface.OnDismissListener on your AlertDialog, so instead of:

```
return builder.create();
```

Try:

```
AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
dialog.setOnDismissListener(new DialogInterface.OnDismissListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
        // do your stuff now
    }
});
return dialog;
```

Comment: The problem is the part of the program I want to execute is in another class and since I've made custom AlertDialog class.

Comment: By "another class" do you mean another Activity? If so you can pass data back using Activity.setResult(int, Intent) where the Intent contains your data as extras.

Comment: The AlertDialog is displayed in the same activity as the rest of the program I want to execute, but I've made a custom class for this AlertDialog. I'm passing parameters through interface, so that isn't a problem. My problem is code executing before any inputs/decisions are made from the user.

Comment: As already mentioned, put the code you want to execute when the user makes a selection into either the buttons' OnClickListeners or in the dialog's OnDismissListener.  The method in your activity that launches the dialog just returns and the rest of your program just waits until one of the listeners is triggeted and calls back. This is a fundamental concept with an event-driven user interface.

Comment: Do you really mean that "You can't wait for the dialog to be dismissed"? I interpreted that this is about being event-driven. That is, that the program must perform all the tasks regardless of the order in which they're performed.

Comment: Yes, that is what I meant to say. To clarify, if you you compare behaviour of AlertDialog with Swing MessageBox for example, a call to MessageBox halts execution on the calling thread and then continues after the MessageBox dialog returns a completion status. This is what I meant by "wait". Conversely, AlertDialog asynchronously shows a dialog and processing on the UI thread continues without waiting for AlertDialog to complete, so you need some event listener to perform any action after the dialog is dismissed (e.g. DialogInterface.OnDismissListener, or DialogInterface.OnClickListener, etc)